# Maximum limit of CSS classes that can be assigned to HTML element?

Tags: html, css

How many number of CSS classes can be assigned for an HTML element.

Comment: You intend to store your database as CSS classes or what?

Comment: Some interviewer asked me like this.And i want the exact number of it which browser support how many classes.

Comment: It's a horrible interview question. There's no reason why anybody would need to *know* this. For all practical intents and purposes, if you're using more than 5 on a single element, then most likely you're doing something wrong.

Comment: +1 on "it's a horrible interview question".

Comment: I thought it was good practice to create a class for each and every styling, then add that class to the element? class=" fontred sizelarge alightleft5px alignright150px" /end scarcasm

Comment: I guess the interviewer was expecting an answer: "infinity unless the browser has a practical limitation". If this is not the answer he is expecting then don't join the company. If the company hired him then it must be full of such idiots.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: Is there a limit on how many classes an HTML can have?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354921/css-is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-classes-an-html-can-have)

Answer (score 10):

I don't think there's a limit. A quick Google search yielded [this](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/maximum-number-of-supported-classes-per-element/).

Comment: Good find. For those who don't want to click the link, the answer is "over 2000"

Comment: And even then, is this a limit on the number of classes or the length of the class string?

Answer (score 7):

The [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-class) does not specify any limitation, but individual browsers may have practical ones.

Answer (score 4):

There are no such limitations imposed by the specification:

### class

> The attribute, if specified, must have a value that is a set of
> *space-separated tokens* representing the various classes that the
> element belongs to.
>
> A set of *space-separated tokens* is a
> string containing **zero or more words**
> separated by one or more space
> characters, where words consist of any
> string of one or more characters, none
> of which are space characters.of which are space characters.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure IE6 only supports up to 2. Modern browers have no limit as far as i know.

Answer (score 1):

One of the lesser known tricks with CSS is the fact that you don't have to limit your elements to just one class. **If you need to set multiple classes on an element**, you add them simply by separating them with a space in your attribute. For example:

```
<p class="pullquote btmmargin left">...</p>
```

**So there is no limit on no of classes you apply.**

Comment: yes so the ans is there is no limit on no of classes you apply on one element

Comment: he is not asking for a theoretical answer