# multiple classes on single element html

Tags: html, css

Is it a good practice to use many classes on one single HTML element? For example:

```
<div class="nav nav-centered nav-reversed navbar navigation-block"></div>
```

I don't mean that two or three classes on one element is bad, but how about four, five or even six?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354921/css-is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-classes-an-html-can-have

Answer (score 70):

### Short Answer

Yes.

---

### Explanation

It is a **good practice** since an element can be a part of different *groups*, and you may want specific elements to **be a part of more than one group**. The element can hold an infinite number of classes in HTML5, while in HTML4 you are limited by a [specific length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1496165/1451422).

The following example will show you the use of multiple classes.

The first class makes the text `color` **red**.

The second class makes the `background-color` **blue**.

See how the *DOM Element* with multiple classes will behave, it will wear *both* CSS statements at the same time.

**Result:** multiple CSS statements in different classes will **stack up**.

You can read more about [**CSS Specificity**](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

---

### CSS

```
.class1 {
    color:red;
}

.class2 {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="class1">text 1</div>
<div class="class2">text 2</div>
<div class="class1 class2">text 3</div>
```

### [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qS9rn/)

Comment: Nice answer - nice formatting :)

Comment: @relic180 The behavior will remain the same: CSS statements will just stack up.

Comment: @Ghillied But that's not the question. The question being asked is "is it bad" to use a large number of classes. Not; is it possible... or, how does it work.

Comment: @relic180 The question being asked is *Is it a good practice to have multiple classes on an HTML element*. The answer is *yes*. It is also valid and complies within W3c specifications. The rest of the answer is opinion-based and it is against SO guidelines, so I won't go into the specific *I think you should do that or this* part of the question/answer.

Comment: @Ghillied I understand what you're saying... but read the last paragraph of the question. He's explicitly drawing a distinction between using 2-3 classes, and using 4-6 classes.. and then specifically asking about the later and NOT the former.

Comment: @relic180 I edited my first paragraph, stating about length of the class attribute, thus answering about the number of classes. But I see what you mean, although a *good* answer to this can't be formulated with undeniable facts.

Comment: late comment but just wanted to point out if you added a `color:green` on class2, whatever order (top to bottom) your CSS file is in is the last style to be applied. e.g. class 2. http://i.imgur.com/f2q19Dl.png

Answer (score 5):

It's a good practice if you need them. It's also a good practice is they make sense, so future coders can understand what you're doing.

But generally, no it's not a good practice to attach 10 class names to an object because most likely whatever you're using them for, you could accomplish the same thing with far fewer classes. Probably just 1 or 2.

To qualify that statement, javascript plugins and scripts may append far more classnames to do whatever it is they're going to do. Modernizr for example appends anywhere from 5 - 25 classes to your body tag, and there's a very good reason for it. jQuery UI appends lots of classnames when you use one of the widgets in that library.