# is this allowed? asigning 2 classes in html

Tags: html, class, assign

Hi is this allowed in html? Can i assign 2 classes at once?

*myImages *and* 
lazy*

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="/pictures/webp/2.webp" type="image/webp">
  <img class="myImages lazy" id="myImg" src="/pictures/2.jpg"  alt="">
</picture>
```

many thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, this is how bootstrap works,based on no. of predefined classes.

Answer (score 0):

yes. You can assign any number of classes you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

In your CSS, you can then target an element that has both classes with `.myImages.lazy`, if you need to.

See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is allowed , actually you can add as many as you want as long you seperate them with a space

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use more than one class and it is good habit.For example Bootstrap is using this widely. There are many [advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30091557/what-are-the-advantages-of-assigning-multiple-classes-to-an-html-element) of using multiple `css` classes.