# Add a plus/minus sign to a jQuery menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I developed the following code for a simple menu:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".main_menu_01, .main_menu_02").on('click', function () {
    
    var $panel = $(this).next('.panel');
    if ($panel.is(':visible')) {
      $panel.add($panel.find('.panel')).slideUp(500).removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $panel.slideDown(500).addClass('active');
    }
    
    });
});
```

```css
.panel{ 
 width: 100%;
 padding-left: 0%;
 font-weight: bold;
 overflow: hidden;
 display:none;
}

.main_menu_01 {
 padding-left: 1%;
 background: blue;
}

.main_menu_02 {
 padding-left: 5%;
 background: lime;
}

.sub_menu_01{
 padding-left: 1%;
 background: lime;
}

.sub_menu_02{
 padding-left: 10%;
 background: lime;
}


.main_menu_01:before, .main_menu_02:before {
 content:'+';
 width:20px;
 display:inline-block;
}

.main_menu_01.active:before, .main_menu_02.active:before {
 content:'-';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="main_menu_01"> 1.0 Main Menu </li>
  <ul class="panel">
        
    <li class="sub_menu_01"> 1.1 Sub Menu </li>
     
    <li class="main_menu_02"> 1.2 Sub Menu </li>
      <ul class="panel">
  
      <li class="sub_menu_02"> <a> 1.2.1 Sub Menu </a> </li>
      <li class="sub_menu_02"> <a> 1.2.2 Sub Menu </a> </li> 

      </ul> 
   
  </ul>
```

All this works fine so far. You can also find the code in the JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ogbn8x6v/2/).

---

As you can see I want to add a `+` and `-` sign to the `main_menu` buttons depending if the menu is opened or not. Therefore, I tried to go with the `before` code in the `CSS`. However, currently the `+` sign remains although the menu is opened.

I am not sure if this issue might be caused by the `jQuery` code. However, I need this `jQuery` code to close/open the entire menu in case the button `main_menue_01` is clicked.

Do you have any idea what I need to change in my code so I can have the full function provided by the `jQuery` code and a `+/-` sign?

Comment: If you look at the changing class attributes in your browser’s inspector, you’ll notice that the element which receives the `active` class (`<ul>`) is not the same as the element you’ve attached your `+`/`-` to (`<li>`).

Comment: Make separate classes for active/inactive which handles the +/- and add/remove those classes in your if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `active` class on the banner, i.e. where the click happens. From there you can change the style with respect to state, e.g.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".main_menu_01, .main_menu_02").on('click', function () {
      var $panel = $(this).next('.panel');
      if ($panel.is(':visible')) {
        $panel.add($panel.find('.panel')).slideUp(500);
        $(this).hasClass('main_menu_01') ? $('.menu').removeClass('active') : $(this).removeClass('active');
      } else {
        $panel.slideDown(500);
        $(this).addClass('active');
      }
    });
});
```

```css
.panel{ 
 width: 100%;
 padding-left: 0%;
 font-weight: bold;
 overflow: hidden;
 display:none;
}

.main_menu_01 {
 padding-left: 1%;
 background: blue;
}

.main_menu_02 {
 padding-left: 5%;
 background: lime;
}

.sub_menu_01{
 padding-left: 1%;
 background: lime;
}

.sub_menu_02{
 padding-left: 10%;
 background: lime;
}

 .main_menu_01:before, .main_menu_02:before {
 content:'+';
 width:20px;
 display:inline-block;
}

.main_menu_01.active:before, .main_menu_02.active:before {
 content:'-';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="menu main_menu_01"> 1.0 Main Menu </li>
  <ul class="panel">
        
    <li class="sub_menu_01"> 1.1 Sub Menu </li>
     
    <li class="menu main_menu_02"> 1.2 Sub Menu </li>
      <ul class="panel">
        <li class="sub_menu_02"> <a> 1.2.1 Sub Menu </a> </li>
        <li class="sub_menu_02"> <a> 1.2.2 Sub Menu </a> </li> 
      </ul> 
  </ul>
```

Comment: Hi onyx, thanks for your answer but it only works partly. If you open main_menu_01 and main_menu_02 and after that you close all menus by clicking on main_menu_01 and then you open the menu again by clicking on main_menu_01 the main_menu_02 will have a - sign but it should be a + sign.

Comment: @Michi, I updated so if you close the `main_menu_01` it won't close the inner one.

Comment: Sorry if my previous comment was not so clear but the functionality of closing and opening the menu worked exactly the way I wanted it before. Only the +/- sign did not work properly. What I need is: If you close the main_menu_01 I want that that the inner one is closed as well AND that the + sign of the inner one changes to a - sign.

Comment: Nice. Exactly how I need. Would be cool if you upvote my question.

Comment: I also updated the JSfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ogbn8x6v/3/. Guide about using multiple classes can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366432/multiple-classes-on-single-element-html